# Find out that driver is installed properly

Tags: linux, drivers, sata

I have got a pci sata controller on my machine. I am not sure that the driver is installed properly.

The `lspci -v` output of the card is:

```
00:09.0 RAID bus controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6421 IDE RAID Controller (rev 50)
Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6421 IDE RAID Controller
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
I/O ports at cc00 [size=16]
I/O ports at d000 [size=16]
I/O ports at d400 [size=16]
I/O ports at d800 [size=16]
I/O ports at dc00 [size=32]
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 40000000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: sata_via
Kernel modules: sata_via
```

Could you please help me to examine that this driver is installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

There are two indications from this output that it is.  First it indicates that the driver is in use(sata_via).  The second is that it says what kind of card it is after the PCI address in the first line.  If the driver is not loaded properly it'll say something like "Unknown Device ID 4000x288...".